# Setting keyboard and regional settings from boxstarter

Tags: windows, deployment, regional-settings

How do I change the change the keyboard and regional settings using a Boxstarter script? Is it possible to do it without resorting to a powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you would need to resort to powershell to do this but it may not be so bad. If you are setting up a system on windows 8/2012 or later you can use Set-WinUserLanguageList to change the keyboard layout:

Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US